# How do you use Textureview as a preview for cameraX [Java]

Tags: java, android-camerax, textureview

I followed the guides on cameraX which all use PreviewView for displaying the camera output using
`preview.setSurfaceProvider(PreviewView.createSurfaceProvider());`

How do I set the preview to use a textureview instead of a PreviewView

Comment: May I ask why do you need to use TextureView? PreviewView uses TextureView internally. Displaying the preview correctly is no trivial matter. If you wish to DIY, you can take a look at PreviewView's source code on how it's handled. https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/camera/camera-view/src/main/java/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView.java

Answer (score 4):

You can specify which view to use in PreviewView between SurfaceView and TextureView.
Before setting surfaceProvider, set the implementation mode

`previewView.implementationMode = PreviewView.ImplementationMode.COMPATIBLE`

Here previewView is the XML id of PreviewView. `PreviewView.ImplementationMode.COMPATIBLE` is for TextureView. After setting this, the PreviewView will use TextureView to show Camera.

The implementation mode for SurfaceView is `PreviewView.ImplementationMode.PERFORMANCE`

This is compatible with

```
androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha22
```